# Create a column with fixed values

Tags: python, pandas, random

I am trying to create a new column in dataframe with values :

```
data = [4.91,4.93,5.02,4.93,4.82,4.57,4.49,4.57,4.54,4.52,4.56,4.73]
```

I have more than 50,000 rows in the dataframe and I want the values to be assigned randomly to the new column.

so the idea is that these values would be assigned randomly and repeated in the column.

I was thinking of using lambda function with this logic :

```
df.assign(value=lambda x: #function here)
```

Can anyone suggest any other way or a simpler way for the same? I am not able to understand the logic the function for assigning the values randomly.

Thanks

Comment: `df['value'] = pd.np.random.choice(data, df.shape[0])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with length of `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})

data = [4.91,4.93,5.02,4.93,4.82,4.57,4.49,4.57,4.54,4.52,4.56,4.73]

df = df.assign(value=np.random.choice(data, len(df)))
print (df)
   A  value
0  7   4.93
1  8   4.91
2  9   4.54
3  4   4.49
4  2   4.56
5  3   4.82
```

Comment: This is putting other values as well instead of the values mentioned in array. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: @vp7 - hmmm, I think not possible, only reason should be float accuracy of values in list - so seems values are different.